# Oracle - SQLLDR Command Line

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

Is it possible to call out the file path from a column in a table to dynamically run multiple import files?

My script currently is

```
$sqlldr userid=XX/XX control=C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\inserttest.ctl log=C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\inserttest.log;
```

This script runs properly. What I am attempting to do is something like this:

```
$sqlldr userid=XX/XX control=(select ctlfilepath from MASTERDATA where Table_Name='BOM') log=(select logfilepath from MASTERDATA where Table_Name='BOM');
```

The purpose would be for me to put all of my file paths into one table and call them out more dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

However, you might want to consider using external table, rather than sqlloader. Using external tables, you can dynamically modify the files that make up an external table.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some research on external tables and see if they can help me.